# Google Deprecated WebView for OAuth

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-ad-b2c

Google recently announced that they are [deprecating OAuth via a webview](https://developers.googleblog.com/2016/08/modernizing-oauth-interactions-in-native-apps.html).

Since B2C is a server side process, is this still going to work?

Answer (score 1):

Based on my understanding, the blog you mentioned is declaring that the Google not allow that **OAuth requests to Google in embedded browsers known as “web-views”**.

***In the coming months, we will no longer allow OAuth requests to Google in embedded browsers known as “web-views”, such as the WebView UI element on Android and UIWebView/WKWebView on iOS, and equivalents on Windows and OS X.***

It means that it will only affect the native apps which using the “web-views”. It doesn’t matter when you use the B2C if you were developing an web application.

Comment: Thanks for responding.  Actually, the app I'm developing has both native and web browser access.  Won't B2C actually be showing me a web-view on my native device?

Comment: Based on my understanding, it depends on how you developing the native application. It will not work If you used the **web-views** in your native application, And if you browser the web page with device browser, the OAuth should still work.